# Bash script - compile and run c++ code for coding competitions

Tags: c++, bash, gcc

This is a simple bash script that I use to compile and run single C++ files for coding competitions.

Features:

- Detects if there is a corresponding `.in` file next to it, and if so uses that as stdin

  - e.g. if the file `problem1.cpp` and `problem1.in` are in the same directory, the script will redirect stdin from `problem1.in`
- Compile each file to a temp directory so it doesn't clutter the working directory
- Configurable g++ warning flags as needed

Note: `\033[32m` and `\033[0m` are terminal color codes that make the text green

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Compiles and runs .cpp code
# if there exists an .in file next to the .cpp file
# it will use that as input

if [ -z $1 ]; then
  echo -e "Please choose an input file"
  exit 1
fi

FILE="$1"
FILE_IN="${FILE%.*}.in"

clear
echo -e "\033[32mCompiling...\033[0m"
TMPFILE=$(mktemp /tmp/run-cpp.XXXXXXXXXX)
WARNING_FLAGS="-Wuninitialized -Wmaybe-uninitialized"
g++ $FILE -std=c++17 $WARNING_FLAGS -O3 -o $TMPFILE

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo -e "\033[32mRunning...\033[0m"
  if [ -f $FILE_IN ]; then
    $TMPFILE < $FILE_IN
  else
    $TMPFILE
  fi
  ERROR=$?
fi
rm $TMPFILE 2> /dev/null
exit $ERROR
```

Usage:
`./runcpp.sh /path/to/my-cpp-file.cpp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> ```

I don't see why you're using Bash for this - there should be no problem using standard POSIX shell.

> ```
> if [ -z $1 ]; then
> ```

I would recommend `"$1"` there, even though extra arguments will cause `[` to return false for other reasons.  Passing as a single argument won't emit any error messages.

> ```
>   echo -e "Please choose an input file"
> ```

`echo -e` isn't portable, and isn't necessary here anyway.

> ```
> FILE="$1"
> FILE_IN="${FILE%.*}.in"
> ```

Avoid all-caps names for variables in your own program - these are generally reserved for environment variables which change programs' behaviour.

> ```
> clear
> ```

I think that's a bit rude - some of us like to be able to compare results against the previous run.  If I want to clear before I run, I can type that easily.

> ```
> echo -e "\033[32mCompiling...\033[0m"
> ```

Don't embed terminal-specific escape codes like that!  Even though most recent terminals support the ANSI escapes, there are others - and if you redirect to file, you don't want it littered with control characters.  Use `tput` to generate the correct escapes for your `$TERM` (and slightly more readable code).

> ```
> TMPFILE=$(mktemp /tmp/run-cpp.XXXXXXXXXX)
> ```

That's not a very descriptive variable name.  It's more informative to say what it's *for* (the executable to create).  And why hard-code `/tmp` as the directory?  Prefer `$TMPDIR` if set (perhaps systems with per-user temp directories, or with a choice of fast or large temporary storage).

> ```
> WARNING_FLAGS="-Wuninitialized -Wmaybe-uninitialized"
> ```

That's quite a lax set of warnings.  If you care about the quality of your source, add a few more.  I suggest `-Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Weffc++`.  If you only care about performance, then perhaps `-Wall -Wextra -Wno-parentheses -Warray-bounds` might be sufficient.

Since we use this variable only once, perhaps we should inline its use, thereby not triggering a Shellcheck warning where we (correctly) expand it without quotes.

> ```
> g++ $FILE -std=c++17 $WARNING_FLAGS -O3 -o $TMPFILE
> ```

`"$FILE"` here, too.  I'd write `"$TMPFILE"` even though we constructed it to be a safe name.

> ```
> if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
> ```

Anti-pattern - just use the preceding command directly after `if`.  Or, enable the `-e` flag of the shell, to just exit if the compilation fails.

> ```
>   echo -e "\033[32mRunning...\033[0m"
> ```

`tput` again.

> ```
>   if [ -f $FILE_IN ]; then
> ```

Quotes again.

> ```
>     $TMPFILE < $FILE_IN
>   else
>     $TMPFILE
>   fi
> ```

As we don't use stdin, we could just redirect `stdin` using `exec`, and not need two different commands.

> ```
>   ERROR=$?
> fi
> rm $TMPFILE 2> /dev/null
> ```

Why didn't we remove the temporary file if we exited early?

> ```
> exit $ERROR
> ```

We wouldn't need to store the error if we made removing the temp-file an exit trap.

---

## Modified code

```
#!/bin/sh
# Compiles and runs C++ source code. A corresponding file
# ending with .in will be used as input, if present

set -eu

if [ $# -ne 1 ] || [ -z "$1" ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 SOURCE"
  exit 1
fi

executable=$(mktemp -t run-cpp.XXXXXXXXXX)
trap 'rm $executable' EXIT

green=$(tput setaf 2)
normal=$(tput sgr0)

echo "${green}Compiling...${normal}"
g++ -o "$executable" -std=c++17 -O3                     \
    -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses      \
    -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Weffc++                  \
    "$1"

echo "${green}Running...${normal}"
input=${1%.*}.in
if [ -f "$input" ]
then exec <"$input"
fi

"$executable"
```

You might also be interested in [my approach to a similar situation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/165861/75307), which uses Make rather than shell.

Answer (score 2):

The other review makes most of the points I would have, so I'll just add three more points.

### Don't ignore the return value of `mktemp`

For security reasons, `mktemp` will refuse to create a file if the name it has chosen already exists.  This is to avoid [security flaws](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Insecure_Temporary_File).  You will probably be saved because `/tmp/` should always have the sticky bit set, preventing users other than the owner of the file from deleting it. Still, I'd recommend a construction like this instead:

```
TMPFILE=$(mktemp /tmp/example.XXXXXXXXXX) || exit 1
```

Another option would be to omit the output file name and just allow the compiler to create `a.out` in the local directory, bypassing the issue entirely as well as shortening your script.

### Use the result directly instead of testing `$?`

The code includes this:

```
g++ $FILE -std=c++17 $WARNING_FLAGS -O3 -o $TMPFILE
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
```

But this could be made a little more direct:

```
if g++ $FILE -std=c++17 $WARNING_FLAGS -O3 -o $TMPFILE ; then
```

Or perhaps better, see the next suggestion.

### Consider using functions

I'd suggest it may be useful to create functions, such as `run` and `compile` to make the script a little easier to understand.  For example:

```
compile() {
    WARNING_FLAGS="-Wuninitialized -Wmaybe-uninitialized"
    g++ "$1" -std=c++17 $WARNING_FLAGS -O3 -o "$2"
}

if compile "$FILE" "$TMPFILE"; then
```

Comment: Also, this [alternative approach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124479/from-q-to-compiler-in-less-than-30-seconds) uses Python.

Comment: I did mention that testing `$?` is an antipattern.  But your explanation is more helpful, since it shows the fix, whereas mine is hidden in the rewritten script.  (In fact, it's not even there, due to `set -e`).